# Prisma queryRawUnsafe doesnt work with INTERVAL

Tags: prisma

Prisma version 4.16.1

I tried two queries:

This one does not work and returns only last record:

```
prisma.$queryRawUnsafe(
    `SELECT * FROM "HouseholdExpenditure"
     WHERE created_at >= NOW() - (INTERVAL '$1 days')`,
     1000
)
```

When I substitute inside the string (literally) with the real valu then it works.
This one works and returns all the record from 1000 days ago:

```
prisma.$queryRawUnsafe(
    `SELECT * FROM "HouseholdExpenditure"
     WHERE created_at >= NOW() - (INTERVAL '1000 days')`,
)
```